# Email notification

Tags: email

Im trying to enrich this notification with subject (post title) and content, rather than its current view and edit links, could anyone help?

```
<?php

function __notify_admin_on_publish( $new_status, $old_status, $ticket )
{
if ( $new_status != 'publish' || $old_status == 'publish' )
    return;

$message = 'View it: ' . get_permalink( $ticket->ID ) . "\nEdit it: " . get_edit_post_link( $ticket->ID );
if ( $post_type = get_post_type_object( $ticket->post_type ) )
    wp_mail( get_option( 'admin_email' ), 'New ' . $post_type->labels->singular_name, $message );

}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', '__notify_admin_on_publish', 10, 3 );
?>
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: Nothink, It works fine. It sends an email but with just two links one for viewing the post and the other to edit. I want somethink more content enriched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$ticket` is a [`WP_Post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) object. It should have all of the information you need. Just add that information to the `$message` string to create whatever content you want. Bare-bones example:

```
$message = 'You are viewing '.$ticket->post_title;
$message .= 'Post Content: '.$ticket->post_content;
$message .= 'View it: ' . get_permalink( $ticket->ID ) . "\nEdit it: " . get_edit_post_link( $ticket->ID );
```

If that isn't what you are looking for, I am certain I don't understand the question.